# Что лучше использовать Tomcat или Jetty?

Tags: tomcat, jetty

Информацию в Интернете не получилось найти, на англ. версии StackOverflow ответ является устаревшим, также как и на других сайтах. Интересно знать на 2019 год, что может быть более востребованным из них двоих.

Объясните, что и в каких ситуациях лучше использовать.

Comment: а что вам от него надо?

Comment: Хотелось бы в целом концепты узнать, что и в каком плане будет лучше. Например, какой более оптимизированный, использует меньше памяти, легче в управлении.

Comment: ... или Wildfly?

Comment: Вот и интересует, потому что много вариантов и непонятно какой будет получше и для чего.